# Why is my array incorrect for my shell script?

Tags: arrays, bash, sh

I have been searching everywhere for an answer to this question. I have an array in my shell script, but when I run it, I get this error: `"(" unexpected`

What am I doing wrong here:

`array=( 1 2 3 4 5 )`

I am using Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are running your script with `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`. There are no arrays in `sh`.

```
choroba@cyan ~$ /bin/sh
$ a=( 1 2 3 )
/bin/sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Answer (score 0):

are you using bash?

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$ array=( 1 2 3 4 5 )
$ echo ${array[1]}
2
$
```

Comment: Yes, this works fine. However, the script isn't running for some reason.

Comment: Weird... When I copy paste entire script into terminal, it works. Why doesn't work as an external file?

Comment: @user1068559 you can try running the script with sh --verbose -x script.sh and see where it actually breaks http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html might help you as well

Comment: Hmm... not revealing much unfortunately. I know the script works, so it must be some kind of quirk with something else.

Answer (score 0):

Also sometime it's because of extra space:

```
array = (1 2 3 4)
```

is not right. It should be:

```
array=(1 2 3 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the word `bash` when running the script as follows:

```
$ bash script.sh
```